# Internet Explorer 11 não mostra imagem

Tags: internet-explorer

O Internet Explorer 11 aqui na empresa não mostra UMA imagem que está alojada no nosso site. Podem testar pelo link [Link para a imagem](https://www.nomalism.com/assets/media/img/logo_header.jpg)

Aparece no Chrome, Firefox, no Edge, mas não no explorer 11.

Já confirmei as configurações do IE, está tudo ok. São cerca de 6 computadores aqui da empresa onde a imagem não aparece. Alguma dica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa imagem está com a extensão errada. É uma imagem PNG (e não JPEG), de acordo com o comando [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file).

```
$ file logo_header.jpg
logo_header.jpg: PNG image data, 903 x 167, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Os outros navegadores certamente utilizam alguma técnica para identificar o tipo de arquivo ao invés de confiar na extensão, diferentemente do IE11.

Portanto, basta renomear `logo_header.jpg` para `logo_header.png`.

Comment: Só porquê a imagem é transparente você entendeu que ela é um `.png` ?

Comment: @DeeSouza percebi que não era JPG porque tinha transparência, mas até aí podia ser TIFF, GIF ou alguma outra coisa (?). Confirmei que era PNG com o comando file.

Comment: Passam-se horas a olhar e à procura de soluções que acabamos por não ver o que deveria ser obvio. Obrigado. Já funciona!